# javascript - Add and Drop cant validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to do a puzzled image CAPTCHA, and make a random set of image appear everytime user visit the page,  but in validation i cant validate it. i was using a jquery and php. im using a switch case to make a random set of image appear every time user visit the page.

when i place all the pieces of image.. the message that saying "proceed into next step not appear."

```
<?php

        srand( microtime() * 1000000 );
        $num = rand(1,5);

        switch ($num){
            case 1: $image_names = "xxnr,ibhy,zabr,atrw,sbnd,htny,aoxt,dslj,awxn";
            break;

            case 2: $image_names = "jyzf,ttnl,lbka,dpil,wyzi,bble,oefw,lxwt,rclj";
            break;

            case 3: $image_names = "tdom,fach,urxn,ceqf,bgbr,xwyc,yyxp,fznw,mhwq";
            break;

            case 4: $image_names = "bgts,deas,zwmd,lmul,ukll,iewn,ltbm,fbvr,gwai";
            break;

            case 5: $image_names = "tlbe,tvul,vrml,zlgu,jymm,ysvs,fcsx,mode,nala";
            break;
        }

        $images = explode(',', $image_names);
        shuffle($images);


        $new_width = "300";
        $new_height= "300";
    $split_size= "100";

        echo "<ul id='sortable' style='width:" . $new_width . "px;height:" . $new_height . "px;'>";

        foreach ($images as $key => $image_name) {
            echo "<li class='ui-state-default' id='recordArr_$image_name' style='border:none;width:" . $split_size . "px;height:" . $split_size . "px;'>
                        <img src='images/$image_name.jpg' /></li>";
        }

        echo "</ul>";
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#sortable").sortable({
                opacity: 0.6,
                cursor: 'move',
                update: function() {


                    var  correctString = " <?php echo ($image_names) ?> ";
                    var currentString = '';


                    $('#sortable li').each(function(){
                        var imageId = $(this).attr("id");
                        currentString += imageId.replace("recordArr_", "")+",";
                    });

                    currentString = currentString.substr(0,(currentString.length) -1);

                    if(currentString == correctString){
                                          alert("proceed into next step");

                        }

                    console.log(currentString);

                }

     });


            });



    </script>
```

i hope anybody can help me..
thanks for your help..

Comment: what do you mean by 'i can't validate it'?

Comment: when i already match all the pieces of image the alert saying "proceed into next step" not appear..

Answer (score 0):

problem solved.. :)

```
<?php

        srand( microtime() * 1000000 );
        $num = rand(1,5);

        switch ($num){
            case 1: $image_names = "xxnr,ibhy,zabr,atrw,sbnd,htny,aoxt,dslj,awxn";
            break;

            case 2: $image_names = "jyzf,ttnl,lbka,dpil,wyzi,bble,oefw,lxwt,rclj";
            break;

            case 3: $image_names = "tdom,fach,urxn,ceqf,bgbr,xwyc,yyxp,fznw,mhwq";
            break;

            case 4: $image_names = "bgts,deas,zwmd,lmul,ukll,iewn,ltbm,fbvr,gwai";
            break;

            case 5: $image_names = "tlbe,tvul,vrml,zlgu,jymm,ysvs,fcsx,mode,nala";
            break;
        }

        $images = explode(',', $image_names);
        shuffle($images);


        $new_width = "300";
        $new_height= "300";
    $split_size= "100";

        echo "<ul id='sortable' style='width:" . $new_width . "px;height:" . $new_height . "px;'>";

        foreach ($images as $key => $image_name) {
            echo "<li class='ui-state-default' id='recordArr_$image_name' style='border:none;width:" . $split_size . "px;height:" . $split_size . "px;'>
                        <img src='images/$image_name.jpg' /></li>";
        }

        echo "</ul>";
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#sortable").sortable({
                opacity: 0.6,
                cursor: 'move',
                update: function() {


                    var  correctString = <?php echo json_encode($image_names); ?>;
                    var currentString = '';


                    $('#sortable li').each(function(){
                        var imageId = $(this).attr("id");
                        currentString += imageId.replace("recordArr_", "")+",";
                    });

                    currentString = currentString.substr(0,(currentString.length) -1);

                    if(currentString == correctString){
                                          alert("proceed into next step");

                        }

                    console.log(currentString);

                }

     });


            });



    </script>
```

i just only need to use..

```
<?php echo json_encode($image_names); ?>;
```